# Add stylesheet to express app

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, ejs

For my web app I am using ejs with express and parse.com on the backend. 
I am having an issue with adding stylesheet and all the answers to this question I was able to find are not solving my problem. I thought maybe showing my code would help to solve it. 
My stylesheet directory is public/css/style.css

See below the code from cloud/app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

var Movies = Parse.Object.extend('Movies');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var query = new Parse.Query(Movies);
    query.find({

        success: function(results) {
            res.render('movie-list', { movies: results });
        },

        error: function(results, error) {

        }

    });
});


app.listen();
```

And here is my template, located in the views:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Movies</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"    rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
        <ul id="categoryList" class="list-group">

            <%
                for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
                { 
                var movie = movies[i];
            %>

            <li class="list-group-item"><%= movie.get('Movie')%></li>

            <%
                }
            %>

        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with chrome developer tools, network section and see response code for that request?

Comment: Hi! I am getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and the path to my app: http://towatchlist.parseapp.com/public/css/style.css

Comment: What if you try with
```
app.use(express.static('./public', {
    'index': ['index.html']
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but looking at my Parse web apps, my links to stylesheets start with `/`

Try changing

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I keep getting this error: Update failed with ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined even after I added /css....

Comment: I don't know a perfect-single-shot solution (I don't have your whole source and environment) but I can tell you that my app does not have the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` how about trying again without that line?

Comment: lots of answers in stack overflow refer to adding this line app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: It seems so! Looking back at my experience (limited) with Parse.com's express engine, their express seemed to behave a little differently from conventional express. Anyhow, I hope you find the solutions to your problem! If I were you, I would try plugging in different directories to express.static()'s arguments. Maybe `cloud/public` or just `public`. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Mayrice! I just included        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> in the head of my template and deleted        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  Now it works!

Comment: @ViPshnck Great! congratulations :)

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer my own question. I deleted the line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and left link to stylesheet in the head of my template as it is:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Now my stylesheet is working.

Answer (score 2):

Please include following in your app.js:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
```

Now  reference your css as : `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` 
It should work for you.

But i think it's important to understand about express static middleware and why i am telling you to include those lines.

express.static middleware is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application. How it works:

- **Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the
  application directory**

  // GET /style.css etc
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
- **Mount the middleware at "/static" to serve static content only when
  their request path is prefixed with "/static"**

  // GET /static/style.css etc.

  app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
- **Serve static files from multiple directories, but give precedence to
  "./public" over the others**

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

So these are three different ways you can use express static middleware.

Comment: Thank you NarendraSoni! Unfortunately none of this worked for me. I just included        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> in the head of my template and deleted        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use the express generator (npm install express-generator -g), any style have to be added to the /public/stylesheets/style.scss files